# Restrict 1st table row for datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Hi I am currently working on datatables and I wrote a code when a table row has been click there is a specific function that will be called.

The problem is when I click the table row for the table header it also does the function (IT MUST NOT).

Here is a snippet of my code when I click the table row there will be a function called.

```
    $('#response-contact-container').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var table = $('#response-contact-container').DataTable();
    var data = table.row(this).data();
    $('#edit-contact-settings').modal('hide');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

    var community_contacts = ['c_id','firstname','lastname','prefix','office','sitename','number','rel'];
    var employee_contacts = ['eid','firstname','lastname','nickname','birthday','email','numbers','grouptags'];
    var counter = 1;

    var container = document.getElementById("contact-settings-wrapper");

    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }

    for(var i=1; i< data.length; i++) {

        var label = document.createElement("label");
        var input = document.createElement("input");

        if (data[0].charAt(0)=="c") {
            var t = document.createTextNode(community_contacts[i].capitalize());
            label.appendChild(t);
            container.appendChild(label);
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = community_contacts[i];
            input.className = "form-control";
            input.value = data[i];
            container.appendChild(input);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        } else {
            var t = document.createTextNode(employee_contacts[i].capitalize());
            label.appendChild(t);
            container.appendChild(label);
            input.type = "text";
            input.name = community_contacts[i];
            input.className = "form-control";
            input.value = data[i];
            container.appendChild(input);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }

        console.log(data[i]);
        counter++;
    }
    $('#edit-contact').modal('show');
});
```

I want the header be able to not perform the function under the onclick in jQuery, but I don't want it to disable because I want to use the datatables built in feature that sort the cells.

Thanks

Comment: can you place the full code.

Comment: i added the full listener.

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret your question to be the following: when I click on a table row, can I call a click handler if and only if that row has `<td>` elements, not `<th>` elements, i.e. only when it is a non-header row?

To accomplish this, use the jQuery `.has()` selector. Specifically, in your code, instead of

```
...on('click', 'tr', ...
```

use

```
...on('click', 'tr:has(td)', ...
```

In the example below, the selected element's `currentTarget` result shows that it is indeed the row, and not the cell, that is the click's current target. Moreover, it calls the handler function (or not) as follows:

- when you click on a normal data row, i.e. a row with all `<td>` cells
- not when you click on a normal header row, i.e. a row with all `<th>` cells
- when you click on a mal-formed row that (inappropriately) contains both `<th>` and `<td>` rows

You should never form a table row in the last way. However, that example show how the selector is working. Specifically, even if you click on the `<th>` cell in that row, the click handler will still fire *because you are clicking on a cell in a row that contains at least one `<td>` cell*. That should never be what you want, but it illustrates what's going on in terms of what is actually being selected.

```js
var counter = 0;

$('#myTable').on('click', 'tr:has(td)', function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
});

$('#myTable').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
  counter += 1;
  console.log(counter + ' clicks');
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
  border: black solid 1px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>normal header row - cell #1 - &lt;th&gt;</th>
    <th>normal header row - cell #2 - &lt;th&gt;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>malformed (mixed) row - cell #1 - &lt;th&gt;</th>
    <td>malformed (mixed) row - cell #2 - &lt;td&gt;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>normal data row - cell #1 - &lt;td&gt;</td>
    <td>normal data row - cell #2 - &lt;td&gt;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this i only add the :has(td) on my listener and it worked like a charm